# upstream timed out error in Python Flask web app using Gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I deployed my Python Flask app on Ubuntu and I am serving with Gunicorn and nginx.

I followed this tutorial carefully

[Digital Ocean tutorial on Flask deplyment using Gunicorn and Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But at times my application stops and generate a 500 error or a 502 error until I restart the .sock file by doing systemctl restart app

When I check the error logs, I see

```
2016/10/20 23:37:18 [crit] 12366#12366: *47260 connect() to   unix:/home/myusername/myapp/myapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 78.206.179.140, server: 000.111.222.333, request: "GET /goods HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/myusername/myapp/myapp.sock:/live-calls", host: "000.111.222.333", referrer: "http://000.111.222.333/goods"
```

and at times I get the prematurely close connection while reading the upstream error.